# Is it possible to download and keep swift file in a path, and render UI from that.?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to download and keep swift file in a path, and render UI from that?
I want to download the viewControllers from server when the app launches, and save it into a path. Once it is done, I want to use that for the UI and other navigation purpose.
Is it possible with swift files?

Comment: Perhaps you need to think about your requirement in a different way. If you could explain the original requirement, we can try to figure out solutions. But as others pointed out, no you cannot download a swift file and include with your app.

Comment: If this can be done it will revolutionise the way we build apps.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible. All files should be available on build time. What you are trying to do will happen on runtime.

An alive man cannot be born again.

Comment: Hahaha. True though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't download a view controller from a server but you can download a configuration file from a server and save the file in your app's sandbox. You can then use that configuration file to create your user interface at runtime.

However, this would be a lot of work depending on how dynamic you need this to be. And there is nothing built into the standard iOS APIs to support this so you would have to develop your own framework to support this sort of dynamic user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Not is possible, but, you can render a window with a plist e.g, do the logic on a controller that mapping keys from a plist and the behavior, after you can dowloaded and render.